# Clone CSS styled file upload buttons

Tags: html, css, file, clone

I styled an `<input type="file"/>` using CSS. When I click on a `+` button, it will be cloned. However this does only visually happen with an unstyled upload button.

Hint: In order to replace the standard button with a styled one, I set `input[type="file"] { display:none }`. Commenting this line out, the cloned upload buttons become visible, however without styles.

Is there a way to clone CSS styled buttons?

See **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egbqkv3t/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to clone the `label` in addition to the `input`.

This clones the first `label`, while ensuring that it works with its own `input`:

```
$('label').first()
  .clone(true)
  .attr('for','img'+addcounter)
  .insertBefore($('#add'));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lt97yr/)

Comment: Cloning the label, that´s the clue. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, I prefer @gfullam 's answer to my own.  Making the `input` a child of  `label` simplifies things immensely.

Answer (score 2):

### Reconfigure your HTML, then clone the label

Form elements such as `input` can be children of `label` elements ([w3.org, 17.9.1 The LABEL element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)), and doing so will make it easier to clone both with one statement.

Below, I do this and then assign the `id` attribute to the parent label for easier targeting.

```
<label id="img1" class="uploadbutton">Choose File
    <input type="file" name="img1"/>
</label>
```

*Note: You could leave the `id` attribute on the `input` and simply use jQuery's `.parent()` method to get the `label` if you prefer. There is more than one way to paint a fence.*

The script then clones the `label` and its children in one statement. Notice the addition of `.find(input)` to set the attributes on the child `input`.

**Example:**

```js
var addcounter = 2;
$("#add").on('click', function (e) {
    
    //Create a new select box
    $('#img1')
        .clone()
        .attr({
            id: "img" + addcounter
        })
        .insertBefore($('#add'))
        .find("input")
        .attr({
            name: "img" + addcounter
        });
    addcounter++;
});
```

```css
td {
    width: 100px;
}

input[type='file'] {
    display: none;
}

#img2 {
    color: red;
}

#img3 {
    color: blue;
}

.uploadbutton {
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;
    cursor: default;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="img1" class="uploadbutton">Choose File
    <input type="file" name="img1"/>
</label>

<button id="add">+</button>
```

**Update:**

There is an additional benefit to nesting `input` elements within `label` elements, which is that you can freely position the parent `label` while the child `input` inherits that positioning by default.

The `input` then can be relatively or absolutely positioned within it, which is easier than trying to manage the position of two independent siblings and better than applying an unnecessary container element to achieve the same effect.

You don't need to make use of that benefit in this example, but I felt it was worth stating for good measure.

Comment: Agreed.  @wurstbrotrest, consider moving your accepted answer from my post to this one.  My feeling's won't be hurt ; )

Answer (score 0):

You are not styling the `input` at all, you are styling the `label`, and then only cloning the input.  Try also cloning the label.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to adapt [this](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery) for `type="file"`